# Value of insert query not posting to data base

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using following code to insert id and value of text box to into a table of mysql database, id is auto increment, but this code does not insert any value into column of table while id is inserted, Please help.

```
<div>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['addtag']))
{
    $tags_dept = $_POST['$tags_dept'];

    $query = "INSERT into deptag (tagdep) VALUES ('$tags_dept')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
 ?>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('addtag1');">Add Tag for Department</a>
<div id="addtag1" style="display:none;">

<form name="form4" method="post" action="" >

<input type="text" name="tags_dept"  />

<input type="submit" value="ADD" name="addtag" />
</form>



</div>
```

Comment: Your script is probably [prone to SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com) and also [the mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: `$_POST['$tags_dept']` should probably be `$_POST['tags_dept']`, although I reiterate @TimWolla's SQL injection warning.

Comment: I was going to post an answer a minute ago, but **^-- « comments** are just as good as answers and take up a lot less room ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert first your ***MySQL*** to ***MySQLi***.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("YourHost","Username","Password","YourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['addtag']))
{
    $tagsdept = $_POST['$tagsdept'];
    $tagsdept = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$tagsdept); /* PREVENT A BIT OF SQL INJECTION */

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into deptag (tagdep) VALUES ('$tagsdept')");

}
?>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('addtag1');">Add Tag for Department</a>
<div id="addtag1" style="display:none;">

<form name="form4" method="post" action="" >

<input type="text" name="tagsdept"  />

<input type="submit" value="ADD" name="addtag" />
</form>
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```